# Can some one tell me why this css code is not working properly?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, frontend, grid

Here is the JSfiddle complete code link:

[CODE](https://jsfiddle.net/harsh9o9/xnuLr51s/72/)

[my clock code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bn5el.png)

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #0b172a;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 5rem;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.clock-ctr {
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid white;
  height: 80vh;
  width: 80vw;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.hour-ctr {
  grid-area: hour;
}

.min-ctr {
  grid-area: min;
}

.sec-ctr {
  grid-area: sec;
}

.ampm {
  grid-area: ampm;
  background: #bc4123;
}

.time-ctr {
  position: absolute;
  height: 70%;
  width: 90%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  gap: 10px;
  grid-template-areas: "hour min sec" "ampm ampm ampm";
}

h1 {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  letter-spacing: 8px;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}

.time-box {
  background: #bc4123;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: grid;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 28px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h1 class="clock-title">Clock</h1>
  <div class="clock-ctr">
    <div class="time-ctr">
      <div class="hour-ctr time-box">
        <p class="hour-value">00</p>
        <p class="hour-title">Hour</p>
      </div>
      <div class="min-ctr time-box">
        <p class="min-value">00</p>
        <p class="min-title">Minute</p>
      </div>
      <div class="sec-ctr time-box">
        <p class="sec-value">00</p>
        <p class="sec-title">Second</p>
      </div>
      <p class="ampm time-box">AM</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can any one tell me how to improve this code

I tried to make is completely responsive but it is not not working,
I tired to use flex to make the element appear in center of page.
Then I use grid to create the clock layout and i didn't knew how to align the cells so I used grid again in them. I was using rem and em to make responsive code but it didn't work out well. please review my code.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the `font-size` of the `time-box` div that is not responsive (28px whatever the device size), To make it responsive I added `media queries` to change the font depending on the device width, As presented in this example:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #0b172a;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 5rem;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.clock-ctr {
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid white;
  height: 80vh;
  width: 80vw;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.hour-ctr {
  grid-area: hour;
}

.min-ctr {
  grid-area: min;
}

.sec-ctr {
  grid-area: sec;
}

.ampm {
  grid-area: ampm;
  background: #bc4123;
}

.time-ctr {
  position: absolute;
  height: 70%;
  width: 90%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  gap: 10px;
  grid-template-areas: "hour min sec" "ampm ampm ampm";
}

h1 {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  letter-spacing: 8px;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}

.time-box {
  background: #bc4123;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: grid;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

@media (min-width:768px) {
  .time-box {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
@media (min-width:1024px) {
    .time-box {
      font-size: 22px;
     }
}
@media (min-width:1280px) {
  .time-box {
      font-size: 28px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h1 class="clock-title">Clock</h1>
  <div class="clock-ctr">
    <div class="time-ctr">
      <div class="hour-ctr time-box">
        <p class="hour-value">00</p>
        <p class="hour-title">Hour</p>
      </div>
      <div class="min-ctr time-box">
        <p class="min-value">00</p>
        <p class="min-title">Minute</p>
      </div>
      <div class="sec-ctr time-box">
        <p class="sec-value">00</p>
        <p class="sec-title">Second</p>
      </div>
      <p class="ampm time-box">AM</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

You can as well use `calc()` function, so you can calculate your font size relative to the screen width like this:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #0b172a;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 5rem;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.clock-ctr {
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid white;
  height: 80vh;
  width: 80vw;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.hour-ctr {
  grid-area: hour;
}

.min-ctr {
  grid-area: min;
}

.sec-ctr {
  grid-area: sec;
}

.ampm {
  grid-area: ampm;
  background: #bc4123;
}

.time-ctr {
  position: absolute;
  height: 70%;
  width: 90%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  gap: 10px;
  grid-template-areas: "hour min sec" "ampm ampm ampm";
}

h1 {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  letter-spacing: 8px;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}

.time-box {
  background: #bc4123;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: grid;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: calc(18px + 0.390625vw);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h1 class="clock-title">Clock</h1>
  <div class="clock-ctr">
    <div class="time-ctr">
      <div class="hour-ctr time-box">
        <p class="hour-value">00</p>
        <p class="hour-title">Hour</p>
      </div>
      <div class="min-ctr time-box">
        <p class="min-value">00</p>
        <p class="min-title">Minute</p>
      </div>
      <div class="sec-ctr time-box">
        <p class="sec-value">00</p>
        <p class="sec-title">Second</p>
      </div>
      <p class="ampm time-box">AM</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```